# AWS Lambda MemoryError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have memoryError using AWS lambda.

Some context:

I am performing data analysis on a large dataset, and some data manipulations (creation of large dictionaries, dataframe operations) are too Memory consuming to run on my local machine.

I was hoping to be able to execute this code (once, not routinely) on AWS with greater memory.

What I did:
I set up a lambda python environment using layers to have the appropriate libraries to run the code, and then created a lambda function that I try to execute using Test (also updated input data on S3 bucket).

Issue is that I still have a MemoryError, I tried changing the max memory in configuration, but can't seem to put it higher than 3008 (which is obviously not enough).

`'MemorySize' value failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 3008`

What is the best option for me to execute a high memory demanding script once ?

Comment: Are you in a special region? Because you can set up to 10240MB of memory at the moment.

Comment: AFAIK there are problems with higher values than that in eu-central-1 in some accounts at the moment.

Comment: Are you using some intermediary tool that does that validation and is outdated to not reflect the actual upper bound for the lambda memory? Have you tried it via the web console?

Comment: @Jens I am in eu-west-3

Comment: You mention `some data manipulations are too Memory consuming to run on my local machine`, and that the memory needed may be too large for what is available in lambda ATM, is it possible to stream of chunk your data so that not all the data are in memory at once? If so this may make your approach feasible.

Comment: Do you have to use lambda? EC2 instances are available with very large amounts of memory - even terabytes, if you can afford it!